# Travis CI Error: Could not access package manager. Is the system running?

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to use travis CI for one of my projects but I am unable to get it working. I managed to make a .travis.yml config file and builds were passing. But surprisingly builds started failing again when I pushed a commit after a couple of hours. Also, builds failed when i restarted a build which was previously passing. I don't understand why is this happening randomly.

Here is the travis log:
[Travis Log](https://travis-ci.org/AmitBarjatya/RealmMvp/builds/287126452)

and the .travis.yml file looks like this:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
sudo: required
env:
  matrix:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-21  ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - build-tools-26.0.2
    - $ANDROID_TARGET
    - android-26
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-$ANDROID_TARGET
  licenses:
    - android-sdk-preview-license-.+
    - android-sdk-license-.+
    - google-gdk-license-.+
before_install:
  - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
  - echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
  - echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
  - chmod +x gradlew
  - ./gradlew dependencies || true
before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
    - $HOME/.android/build-cache
before_script:
  # Create and start emulator
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi $ANDROID_ABI
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - adb wait-for-device
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

And the gradle file relevant snippet:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amit.realmmvp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

There are similar questions on stack overflow about the same issue but they all relate to android studio and emulator not getting started. But, in travis config file ,I'm already asking it to wait until emulator comes online using   `- adb wait-for-device`

Can anyone please help me figure this out? Thanks.

**EDIT**

The build process fails here:

```
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTestUnable to install /home/travis/build/AmitBarjatya/RealmMvp/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure (Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installRemotePackage(Device.java:1004)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:911)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:122)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:126)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: Could you post a problem part of your Travis Log here?

Comment: It actually fails here :app:connectedDebugAndroidTestUnable to install /home/travis/build/AmitBarjatya/RealmMvp/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure (Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?)

Comment: I asked to post it not in comments but as a part your question. Then your question will look very good.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question. There is also a link at the top "Travis Log" where you can see the entire log if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
  - adb wait-for-device
```

use

```
  - android-wait-for-emulator
```

The [`android-wait-for-emulator`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/blob/master/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator) script not only waits for the device but also for the boot animation too complete.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot. Do you know why the already passed builds failed when i retried them?

Comment: Coincidence... Or they changed something with their containers resulting in these issues.